# UITableViewCell clipping subviews higher than (out of) the cell

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uitableview, uiview

I am creating a `UITableView` with a custom `UITableViewCell`.

Adding some subviews in the cell, and one view's height is higher than the cell, to connection each "`Circle`" together.

(Contents between 2 separators is a `cell height`)

Normally it should work like this:

[image: Image1]

But tableView always clip my view (The gray line) at the bottom randomly like this:

[image]

I've already set `UITableViewCell`

```
self.clipsToBounds = NO;
self.contentView.clipsToBounds = NO;
self.contentView.superview.clipsToBounds = NO;
```

But it's still clipping my contents in the `cell`, 
Can anybody give me some advice? I've been working on the problem for a long time.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of connecting each of the circles with lines connect from the top of the `UITableViewCell` to the bottom of the `UITableViewCell`.

**As long as you always end your line at the same horisontal position, top and bottom, it will look like a continuous line.**

Depending on how flexible you want your line to be you could opt for a very simple implementation.

This example requires you disable the `UITableView` row separator and default selection to avoid a 1pt gap in your vertical line.

Implement the `UITableViewCell` in a Nib file using two `UIImageViews`.

[image: Stations Nib]

Remember to set the reuse identifier on the `UITableViewCell` and you can load your cell in your `UITableViewDataSource` with

```
[tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"MyTableViewCell" bundle:nil]
    forCellReuseIdentifier:@"stations"];

UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"stations"];
```

Your result should look something like this:

[image: Stations cells in simulator]

The line image needs to stretch so turn on vertical slicing on the image in your image asset catalog.